# Get the name of Server.Executed file in ASP classic

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have a global `include.asp` file which contains this code:

```
if SomeCondition then
    Response.Clear
    Response.Status = "404 Not Found"
    Server.Execute "/error404.asp"
    Respnse.End
end if
```

Two other files, `content.asp` and `error404.asp` #include this file.

The content file sets *SomeCondition* to true  causing the error page to *Server.Execute*. However, that same condition will be true inside error page. This creates an infinite loop and I end up with the following error:

```
Server object error 'ASP 0227 : 80004005'
Server.Execute Failed
/include.asp, line 1111
The call to Server.Execute failed
```

How can I avoid the infinite loop? I had these workarounds in mind:

## A

```
if SomeCondition then
    if GetExecutedFileNameSomehow() <> "error404.asp" then
       ' ...
    end if
end if
```

But I cannot seem to get the name of error file through code (I have looked inside server variables, all point variables refer to the calling file i.e. content).

## B

Use a shared variable e.g. set *BeingExecuted = true* in content file and check it inside error file but the problem with Server.Execute is that the executed script cannot access calling file's variables.

Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, due to the nature of Server.Execute, the script being called does not know its real origin and I didn't find any way to find it.

That said, I fear that you'll have to resort to ugly work arounds, most reliable I can think of is using a Session variable as a "shared variable".

In *include.asp* have such code:

```
strFileToExecute = "/error404.asp"
If (Session("currently_executing")<>strFileToExecute) And (SomeCondition) Then
    Response.Clear
    Response.Status = "404 Not Found"
    Session("currently_executing") = strFileToExecute
    Server.Execute strFileToExecute
    Session("currently_executing") = ""
    Response.End
End If
```

The logic is that the Session variable is set right before calling the Execute method. this way when *error404.asp* is executed and including the same code again, the value of the Session variable will be set and you know to abort the operation thus avoid the endless loop.

Comment: Great minds think alike, lol.. or more likely that's about the only way that actually works. :/

Answer (score 0):

If you really MUST include include.asp in 404.asp, I'm hoping your test for "Somecondition" is inside a sub or function. Than you could just define a variable inside include.asp, set this to true in 404.asp and test it in your condition.

Thus:

Inside include.asp

```
Dim blnNot404page : blnNot404page = true
```

Inside 404.asp (and off course in code after you've included include.asp)

```
blnNot404page = false
```

Inside include.asp again

```
if (SomeCondition and blnNot404page) then
    Response.Clear 
    Response.Status = "404 Not Found"
    Server.Execute "/error404.asp"
    Response.End
end if
```

Comment: I am afraid this won't work. Script variables set in outer script (content.asp/include.asp) are not visible inside the executed script (error.asp/include.asp) and vice-versa. This the way ASP is.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that... then I would just make a function call to a procedure that set's the variable to false. It should work, but I'll try to test it out later and update my answer with it as soon as I have a poc.

Comment: Just tested.. I can access the variables in the included script just fine.. so the overhead of a setter function is not needed. My solution off course only works if your codeblock in include.asp is inside a function/sub .. otherwise the outer script can't adjust the parameter fast enough.. Perhaps you should rather use a server.transfer. That way you can use request.servervariables("script_name") to define if your in 404.asp or not.